# Не все переменные привязаны PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

У меня есть процедура:

```
begin
someProcedure(arg1 => 123123,
arg2 => 0,
arg3 => null,
arg4 => :arg4)
end;
```

Тип поля arg4 - out number. Если вставлять туда null\ просто убирать параметр из области аргументов - выходит ошибка. "Обязательных" параметров - то есть таких, которые я передавал в процедуру непосредственно в окне теста процедуры, всего 2 - это arg1, arg2. Что подставить в arg4, чтобы процедура заработала?

Answer (score 3):

> Что подставить в arg4, чтобы процедура заработала?

Переменную, которая должна быть сначала объявлена, или в приложении (`:arg4`), или как переменная PL/SQL (`arg4`). Обратите внимание на разницу в их подстановке - двоеточие.

Вот так:

```
create or replace procedure someProcedure (arg1 int, arg2 int, arg3 int, arg4 out int) is
begin arg4 := arg1+arg2;
end;
/
var arg4 number;
declare
    arg4 number;
begin
    someProcedure (
        arg1 => 123123,
        arg2 => 0,
        arg3 => null,
        arg4 => arg4);
    :arg4 := arg4;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
print arg4

ARG4
------
123123
```